# Maximal Function of $|x|^{-\alpha}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Is it true that if $f_{\alpha}(x)=|x|^{-\alpha}$ with $f_{\alpha} \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, that means $0<\alpha<d$, there exists a constant $C_{\alpha,d}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{M}f_{\alpha}(x)=\sup_{r>0}\dfrac{1}{m(B_r(x))} \int_{B_r(x)} |y|^{-\alpha} dy=C_{\alpha,d}f(x)
\end{align*}
?
If so, when is $C_{\alpha,d}>1$? I am trying to write the integral as
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} m\left( \{y \in B_r(x) : |y|^{-\alpha} >t\right) dt
\end{align*}
but did not lead to any result. Thank you.